# php variable passed to mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, function

Not sure what I am doing wrong?  Never ran into this issue before?  But this is also the first function I have written.

```
<?php
function category($string){
if(preg_match("/(Slimming|Laser|Spa|Massage|Manicure|Pedicure)/i", $string)){  
echo 'Spa';
}
}  // This is function.php

$title = 'Spa';

include 'function.php';
$category = category($title);
$category = mysql_real_escape_string($category);
echo "$category<br>"; // I get Spa
var_dump("$category"); //added for testing, I get string(0) ""
```

$category is then sent to a mysql insert, the value is blank in the database...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'Spa';
```

Should be:

```
return 'Spa';
```

and

```
var_dump("$category");
```

Should be:

```
var_dump($category);
```

Functions should always return a value if you're defining a variable otherwise you're doing nothing.

Comment: No problem, just remember to pick this as the best answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You get the ouput "Spa" when you call `category($title)`, because in the function is `echo` instead of `return`.